# can't get data from List<> to populate data grid view

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

From examples, this seems like it should be very straightforward, but for some reason I can't get data from a List<> to populate a data grid view. I have created a class with 3 fields, created a list of the class and assigned the list to the DataSource property of a DGV.

The list is correctly populated with information, the DGV displays the proper number of rows, but all the textboxes are blank. Can someone please show me what is wrong?

```
List<clsCHPChassis> myList = new List<clsCHPChassis>();

clsCHPChassis chassis1 = new clsCHPChassis("Rear Port", "Management", "192.168.1.1");
clsCHPChassis chassis2 = new clsCHPChassis("Front USB", "Local", "10.10.10.1");

myList.Add(chassis1);
myList.Add(chassis2);

dgv.DataSource = myList;
```

`clsCHPChassis` definition:

```
public class clsCHPChassis 
{
    public string Site = string.Empty;
    public string ChassisName = string.Empty;
    public string IP = string.Empty;

    public clsCHPChassis(string newSite, string newChassisName, string newIP)
    {
        Site = newSite;
        ChassisName = newChassisName;
        IP = newIP;
    }
}
```

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns is set to true? Data in clsCHPChassis is visible via public properties?

Comment: Please provide class definition for clsCHPChassis

Comment: Winforms or Webforms?

Comment: call DataBind method after assign datasource

Comment: try setting dgv.DataSource to null and then to myList.  Just assigning the value doesn't force the RePaint() method to update the control.  It will work the first time without setting null but not an update.

Comment: the textboxed I was referring to are the members of the DGV. I did try setting autogeneratecolumns to true explicitly but no luck. If I don't manually create columns in the control, nothing happens. If I create columns programatically or thru UI, rows are generated equal to the number of list entries, but boxes remain blank, like they cannot determine which property of clsCHPChassis they are bound to. I tried setting DataPropertyName but no luck either

Answer (score 0):

List itself is not enough to set as datasource. you have to use `BindingList<T>` and `BindingSourse` along with it

Another and simple solution is use DataTable as DataSourse

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable("Table");
 table.Columns.Add("Site", typeof(string));
 table.Columns.Add("ChassisName", typeof(string));
 table.Columns.Add("IP", typeof(string)); 

 table.Rows.Add("Rear Port", "Management", "192.168.1.1");
 table.Rows.Add("Front USB", "Local", "10.10.10.1");

 dgv.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: Here's the clsCHPChassis def.

Comment: public class clsCHPChassis
        {
            public string Site = string.Empty;
            public string ChassisName = string.Empty;
            public string IP = string.Empty;           

            public clsCHPChassis(string newSite, string newChassisName, string newIP)
            {
                Site = newSite;
                ChassisName = newChassisName;
                IP = newIP;
            }
        }

Comment: Winforms is the platform. I don't have a dataBind option

Comment: if I put in a breakpoint and probe myList, I can see porperty values in list.

Comment: i am not clear about your requirment. I guess you have a datagridview with  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and you want to fill the textbox from datasours? right?

Comment: correct. I have a standard DGV. I want it to have 3 columns populated by the 3 properties of the clsCHPChassis class. The myList variable is a list of clsCHPChassis that I am passing to DGV as its datasource

Answer (score 0):

Only public properties are databound:

```
public class clsCHPChassis {
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string ChassisName { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Slai, You nailed it! I did not have the clsCHPChassis data set as properties. It works perfectly now! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Slai was able to solve the problem. His answer that only properties of the class are databound was the solution. Changing the 3 fields to properties in the class definition to properties fixed it!